# Kotlin: How to map from Kafka stream

Tags: kotlin, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to map a Kafka `ConsumerRecord` to a `Tuple2`. The only compiler-error-free code I've managed to write is the following:

```
val results = kafkaStream.map<Tuple2<Int,Submission>>({ record ->
            Tuple2(record.key(), record.value())
        }, null)
```

In the place of a null, it requires a `ClassTag` called `evidence`. I have no idea what this is. How can I correctly perform this mapping?